# JDBC MySQL url with Liquibase is wrong

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using Liquibase using a MySQL database.

I provide the following URL:

```
const db_url = `jdbc:mysql://${process.env.MYSQL_HOST}:${process.env.MYSQL_PORT}/${process.env.MYSQL_DB}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&serverTimezone=UTC`;
```

Please ignore `process.env.<XXX>` because I guarantee it is valid and underline values are finally provided.

This gives me an error:

```
 Liquibase Community 4.0.0-beta1 by Datical
Errors:
  No command was passed.
```

By the way, if I provide the following URL:

```
const db_url = `jdbc:mysql://${process.env.MYSQL_HOST}:${process.env.MYSQL_PORT}/${process.env.MYSQL_DB}?serverTimezone=UTC`;
```

It does work, so basically I figured out the URL has problems with multiple queries.

I've read some threads in Stack Overflow and among comments there was one stating that I should use `&amp;` instead of `&` char:

```
const db_url = `jdbc:mysql://${process.env.MYSQL_HOST}:${process.env.MYSQL_PORT}/${process.env.MYSQL_DB}?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8&amp;serverTimezone=UTC`;
```

Still, error:

```
 Liquibase Community 4.0.0-beta1 by Datical
Errors:
  No command was passed.



 /bin/sh: 1: amp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: amp: not found
/bin/sh: 1: --username=admin: not found
```

So how can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the jdbc url in the `liquibase.properties` file?
I found a detailed document about configuring and creating the liquibase.properties file where you add the jdbc url > [Here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/creating-config-properties.html?Highlight=defaults%20file)

BTW you can be a part of Liquibase Forum, where everyone from the Liquibase Community can ask/answer questions, all about Liquibase. >> [Liquibase Forum](https://forum.liquibase.org/)